# concatenate different cells in bold and italic excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub joint()
ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Select
Row = 2
col = 2
For Each Cell In Selection
country = Cells(Row, col)
Name = Cells(Row, col + 1)
honor = Cells(Row, col + 2)

Cells(Row, col + 8) = Name & ", " & country & ", " & honor

Row = Row + 1
Next
End Sub
```

I want to bold name and italicize honor in concatenated form.

for example

**myname**, pak, *ABC*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right after your line:

```
Cells(Row, col + 8) = Name & ", " & country & ", " & honor
```

add this section of code:

```
With Cells(Row, Col + 8)
    .ClearFormats
    .Characters(1, Len(Name)).Font.Bold = True
    .Characters(Len(Name) + 4 + Len(Country), Len(.Value)).Font.Italic = True
End With
```

And keep the rest as it is.

Screen shot of result:
[image]

Comment: oh, It works fine. no problem. I was saying I also tried it but did not get the results